# Responsive items not working in Flask local web server

Tags: html, css, flask, responsive, localserver

I'm developing a Flask webApp in which I have included some responsive items.

For example, the navbar is hided in small screens and replaced with an icon which opens a lateral bar, and the elements of the second section () are a w3-half class which when screen is smaller than 601 px it uses 100% width.

All the elements described above, are working correctly when I open the html page in browser, but, when I use the local web server provided by Flask, they don't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>SkinAnalysis</title>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

   <!-- Necessari pel funcionament del missatge d'alerta -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{url_for('static',filename ='logodef.png')}}">


   <style>
    .mySlides {display:none}
    .w3-left, .w3-right, .w3-badge {cursor:pointer}
    .w3-badge {height:13px;width:13px;padding:0}
    
    .alert {text-align: center; font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif; font-size: calc(14px + (21 - 14) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300)));}

    body {font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;}
    
    span {font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif; font-size: calc(20px + (28 - 20) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300)));}

    .cos {font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif; font-size: calc(14px + (21 - 14) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300)));}
    .barranav {font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif; font-size: calc(14px + (19 - 14) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300)));}
    .titol {font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif; font-size: calc(16px + (23 - 16) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300)));}
    .respicon {font-size: calc(16px + (23 - 16) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300)));}

    body, html {
     height: 100%;
     line-height: 1.5;}

 </style>
</head>


<body>

  <!-- Navbar (sit on top) -->
  <div class="w3-top">
    <div class="w3-bar w3-white w3-card">
      <a href="#home" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"><img src="{{url_for('static',filename = 'cap_def.png')}}" style="width: 180px"></a>
      <!-- Float links to the right. Hide them on small screens -->
      <div class="w3-right w3-hide-small">
        <a href="#projecte" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"><i class="fa fa-briefcase respicon"></i><b class="barranav"> Projecte</b></a>
        <a href="#indicacions" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"><i class="fa fa-list-ul respicon"></i><b class="barranav"> Indicacions</b></a> 
        <a href="#analitza" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"><i class="fa fa-search respicon"></i><b class="barranav"> Analitza't</b></a>
      </div>

      <!-- Hide right-floated links on small screens and replace them with a menu icon -->
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-right w3-hide-large w3-hide-medium" onclick="w3_open()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </a>
    
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Sidebar on small screens when clicking the menu icon -->
  <nav class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-black w3-card w3-animate-left w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large" style="display:none" id="mySidebar">
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-large w3-padding-16"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
   <a href="#projecte" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>  Projecte</a>
   <a href="#indicacions" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"><i class="fa fa-list-ul"></i>  Indicacions</a>
   <a href="#analitza" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>  Analitza</a>
  </nav>

  
  <!-- Flash messages -->
  <div class='w3-container w3-padding'>
      {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
        {% if messages %}
          {% for message in messages %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert" text-align="center">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close"><span aria-hidden="True">&times;</span></button>
              <strong>{{ message }}</strong> Torna a l'apartat Analitza't
            </div>
          
          {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endwith %}
    {% block body %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>

  <!-- Page content -->
  <div class="w3-content w3-padding" style="max-width:1564px">

   <!-- Projecte -->
   <div class="w3-container w3-padding-16" id="projecte">
 <div class="w3-center w3-padding-32">
  <span class="w3-bottombar w3-border-dark-grey w3-padding-8">Què és SkinAnalysis?</span>
 </div>

     <div class="w3-row-padding w3-center" style="margin-top:16px">
        <div class="w3-half" style="padding-right: 15px;">
          <p class="titol"><b>1. Preparació previa</b></p>
          <i class="fa fa-cogs w3-margin-bottom w3-jumbo w3-center"></i>
          <p class="cos" style="text-align: justify;">
            Per tal de poder oferir referents a les dimensions de la lesió, ens has de proporcionar una referència.<br>
          </p>
          <img src="{{url_for('static',filename = 'nomes_linia.png')}}" style="width: 50%">
        </div>
        <div class="w3-half" style="padding-left: 15px;">
          <p class="titol"><b>2. Captura la imatge</b></p>
          <i class="fa fa-camera-retro w3-margin-bottom w3-jumbo w3-center"></i>
          <p class="cos" style="text-align: justify;">
            Un cop preparats per fer la fotografia, assegura't realitzar-la sota unes condicions d'il·luminació que evitin la presència de contrastos indesitjats, com poden ser zones ombrejades per falta de llum.<br>
            Per altra banda, la imatge hauria de mostrar la lesió amb una dimensió adequada i part de la pell del seu contorn.</p>
          <img src="{{url_for('static',filename = 'ex_lesio.jpg')}}" style="width: 50%">

        </div>
      </div>

  <!-- End page content -->
  </div>

<script>

//Toggle between showing and hiding the sidebar when clicking the menu icon 
var mySidebar = document.getElementById("mySidebar");

function w3_open() {
  if (mySidebar.style.display === 'block') {
    mySidebar.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    mySidebar.style.display = 'block';
  }
}

//Close the sidebar with the close button 
function w3_close() {
    mySidebar.style.display = "none";
}
  </script>



</body>

</html>
```

Here I post a reduced version of index.html with the parts that are not working as expected. This template is run in Flask using render_template().

Sorry in advance for all the mistakes that you could detect but I'm not a web programmer, it's for a project...

If more code parts are needed for detecting the problem I will included them!

**EDIT**

I add here two images for ilustrate the problem. First html page visualized in browser and second in local web server.
[image: html page in browser]
[image: web app in local web server]

Comment: Hey! What do you mean exactly by "the URL provided by Flask" and locally ?

Comment: Hi! I wanted to say that, when I run the web in the local server provided by flask, with URL type http://127.0.0.1:5000/ the responsive items don't work. But when I open, for example, the index.html page separately in browser it works as expected.

Comment: Alright and do you have any error if you open the development console ?

Comment: Nope... It doesn't report any error and all the other things works fine. Is only the responsive items I think and I can't find the problem... I've posted two pictures to illustrate the problem. As you can see, the nav bar icon to open lateral bar doesn't appear in the flask one and the automatic change column width either.